# Why is this verse 15.16 mentioned in both Joshua and Judges?

Tags: tanach, shoftim--book-of, joshua--book-of

I have two questions. The first is why is there a repeat of the posuk, one in [Joshua](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.15.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and one in [Judges](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.1.12?lang=bi&with=Rashi%20on%20I%20Chronicles%7CQuoting&lang2=en)?

The second question is: According to Rashi this was only mentioned here to mention the division of the land, but if that is the case, he could just mention that Caleb gave it to his brother?